# ¿Cómo puedo pasar parámetros con vue y ruby on rails para desplegar un video en especifico?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js

Estoy trabajando rails con vue.js y estoy tratando de pasar los parámetros, cuando haga click en una imagen para desplegar el video en especifico.

Este es mi código de como hago la solicitud con "axios" y hago en cambio de vista:

popular.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Popular from './popular.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('popular'))
  const popular = new Vue(Popular).$mount('popular')

})
```

popular_vue.vue

```
  <div v-for="video in videos_p">
        <div class=" m0 featured_img">
            <a v-bind:href="'/programas/' + video.program.slug + '/videos/' + video.slug"><img v-bind:src="video.image_url" alt=""></a>
          </div>
   </div>

<script>
export default {
  data: {
    videos_p: []
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
      .then(response => {
        this.videos_p = response.data
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

con eso paso a la otra vista cuando le hago click a la imagen, con la url de la imagen:

```
http://localhost:5000/programas/detras-de-un-cafe/videos/homenaje-a-matias-arrizabalaga-un-ser-excepcional
```

como puedo recibir los datos en la nueva vista para hacer el despliegue del video que corresponde, este es el codigo de la nueva vista:

index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Index from './Index.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const node = document.getElementById("populars-index")
  const props = JSON.parse(node.getAttribute('data'))
  new Vue({
    render: h => h(Index, {
      props
    })
  }).$mount('#populars-index');
})
```

index.vue:

```
      <div class="col-sm-12 post interview">
        <div class="row m0 featured_img">

          <div class="video">
            <iframe width="640" height="360" src="#" type="mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["apiKey"],
  data: () => ({
    errors: [],
    videos: []
  }),
  mounted() {
    axios.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
      .then(response => {
        this.videos = response.data
      }),
      console.log(this.apiKey);
  }
}
</script>
```

index.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'programs/index'%>

<%= content_tag :div,
id: "programs-index",
data: {
  apiKey: "datos de muetra"
}.to_json do %>
<% end %>
```

Alguna idea de como hacer ese despliegue en especifico?????

Answer (score 0):

Este paso de datos me lo explico un amigo y lo dejo en caso que alguien este con la misma duda:

modifica la routa con el nombre de los parametros:

```
get 'programas/:Pslug/videos/:Vslug' => "programs#index"
```

se agrega dos parametros que obtendran los slug

index.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'programs/index'%>

<%= content_tag :div,
id: "programs-index",
data: {
  videoSlug: params[:Vslug],
  programsSlug: params[:Pslug]
}.to_json do %>
<% end %>
```

index.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ["videoSlug", "programsSlug"],
  data: () => ({
    errors: [],
    videos: []
  }),
  mounted() {
    axios.get('xxxxxxxxxxx' + this.videoSlug) //en este caso la api solo necesita el slug para hacer la busqueda
      .then(response => {
        this.videos = response.data
      }),
      console.log('video slug ' + this.videoSlug) //muestra en consola el parametro como prueba del envio de datos
    console.log('programs slug ' + this.programsSlug)
  }
}
</script>
```

y se imprime :

```
<div v-for="video in videos" class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="row m0 featured_img">
          <div class="video">
            <iframe width="640" height="360" v-bind:src="video.urls_video[1].url" type="mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```